# Which one is preferred, importing from module where a symbol is defined or from the module imported directly?

Tags: python

Given in the example below, symbol A is defined in module a and imported in b. Module c imports b. Should it access A from module a directly or get it from B (the module it imported directly)? I am thinking of the latter so that I don't need to worry about removing direct references to A, if some day I retire references to b from module c.

a.py

```
def A(Exception):
    pass

def funA():
    raise A
```

b.py

```
from a import A, funA

def funB():
    try:
        funA()
    except A as e:
        # some additional handling
        raise
```

c.py

```
import b

# Which of the following is preferred?
# 1. 
try:
    funB():
except a.A:
    # do something

# 2. 
try:
    funB():
except b.A:
    # do something
```

Comment: who owns the code?

Comment: 'A' could be external library e.g. in my case it was redis module. B and C can be modified by the user of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the former because:

- The latter is misleading about the origin of the function.
- Using the latter reduces maintainability as you need to traverse b when looking for the function's definition - only to find that it resides in a.
- Moreover, in case you decide to drop module B and directly import A, your code will break.

However, at the end of the day, it boils down to what you and your team prefer. Regardless of what you choose, I recommend that you stay consistent with the choice.